# X-axis labels illegible. Display every other label on X-axis ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following plot but the x-axis labels are too small to read. If I increase the size they become overlapped and illegible

[image: X axis labels too small]

[I have tried the code form the following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32278215/show-every-nth-row-name-in-ggplot2)

But I get an error 'wrong sign in 'by' argument'

I also tried the following link 
[How to show every second R ggplot2 x-axis label value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147849/how-to-show-every-second-r-ggplot2-x-axis-label-value)

but as a beginner I couldn't quite follow the code and aren't sure if there is an added complication with the labels being dates.

I have a df of 100 genes across 170 samples + a 'Genes' column. I then use the following code to make the data long:

```
mat_dataNew<-mat_data %>% gather(sample, expression, -Genes)
#log10-transform Counts data
mat_dataNew <- mutate(mat_dataNew, log10_NormCounts = log10(expression))
```

I then plot with:

```
ggplot(mat_dataNew, aes(x=reorder(Genes, -log10_NormCounts), y=log10_NormCounts, colour=Group)) +
 geom_point(size=.5) +
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, size=4)) +
 labs(x = "100 most abundant Genes", y = "Gene Expression (Log10 Normalised Counts)")
```

I have tried reading about scale_x_continuous but couldn't seem to find an answer. Could you please help to suggest some code so that the x axis label is legible? I thought maybe the easiest option would be to display every other label???

Comment: How about just using coor_flip() to put text on y-axis and making it a bit more readable? https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_flip.html

Comment: Do you really need to show 100 genes? From the plot you showed, looks like a lot of them are pretty similar

Comment: And you want `scale_x_discrete` not `scale_x_continuous`

Comment: fyi you can use `fct_lump()` to lump similar genes in to a new “other” level
https://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html#modifying-factor-levels

Answer (score 3):

You need `scale_x_discrete` as was said in the comments by Tung.

`scale_x_discrete` has the following three arguments (among others, [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_discrete.html)):

1. `limits` - decides the values and their orders for the **graph**
2. `breaks` - decides which values to display as ticks on the axis
3. `labels` - decides what the ticks actually display as their labels

(In your case, since your gene names are already factors, you do not need the labels argument.)

Set the `limits` argument to all of the genes, set the `breaks` argument to every other gene ([SO ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237557/extract-every-nth-element-of-a-vector)), and add the `scale_x_discrete` to your `ggplot`.

```
ggplot(...+
scale_x_discrete(limits=Genes,breaks=Genes[seq(1,length(Genes),by=2)])+
...)
```

Note: you seem to be reordering your Genes column in the `ggplot` you will need to do the same reordering for the `limits` argument for this to work.